# infopath to add number in the list for sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have three column in my infopath form. 
1. Resources
2. Benefit
3. Total
How do I calculated formula in infopath so when i put number in resources and benefit the total gets calculated automatically.
Eg: when i put resources = 10 and Benefit = 5 Total should automatically add them and display total as 15 in infopath

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Mohammed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click properties for your Total Field and set the default value equal to Resources + Benefit fields.